# jQuery set element attribute on external script

Tags: jquery

I have an external script loaded in the middle of my html page. It will display a form once the page is loaded.

I want to set "placeholder = label name" to the input fields by writing a small piece of script in my own js file loaded from the bottom of the html page. The code is very simple but it didn't do the trick:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#inputexample").attr("placeholder", "min price");
   }
</script>
```

I am not sure why it's not working. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: try $('input') instead

Comment: Sorry it should be an ID not a selector, I have updated the code in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try set little delay before your script runs. Like that:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
         setTimeout(function() {
             $("#inputexample").attr("placeholder", "min price");
         }, 50);
     }
</script>
```

Comment: This one did the trick! Thank you, I had to increase the delay to make it to work. thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The external script is probably using ajax to load the form.
Since ajax is async, the element you are trying to change is not on your page yet.

One way to do this is wait until the ajax is complete by using $(document).[ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) instead of $(document).ready(). Although this will create a very small overhead for each ajax request.

Comment: I am not sure I am doing the right way. I've looked at the external script file source code and couldn't find any ajax load function, as a result I couldn't make .ajaxtComplete() function to work out. But I have learned something new today and maybe it will be very useful in the future. Thank you so much for that.